# How Do You Clean RCA Ports?

Tags: amplifier, cleaning

I have an old amp which is beginning to show wear and scratches on its RCA ports. However, alcohol, water, and a simple cloth dont work and cannot remove the grime on the ports. What is the best substance to use to clean the ports without damaging the amp?

Comment: Looks just like a bit scratched surface and doesn't seem to cause any issues. Why is it so important for you to eliminate those marks?

Comment: The amp has some noise... I took it apart and cleaned the circut boards but I still get noise at high volume.. so I'm thinking it might be the plugs.

Comment: Can you please specify the noise? Was it hum, hiss or buzz?

Comment: Seems like a hum, but I only hear it when its turned up to high volume levels when connected to a quiet device such as an iPod. When watching a movie, etc. I dont hear it since the dial is not turned as high up.

It might actually be my cables (they arent that good) but I dont know.

Comment: With volume set to a **normal listening level**, how close to the speaker must you be to hear the noise? If the answer is a few feet (or less), the noise level is likely normal. If you can hear it from the listening position (or, especially if it intrudes upon the listening experience), this is a problem that warrants further investigation.

Comment: Can't hear any noise at normal listening level when I'm 3 feet from the speaker... guess its normal then. However, will a cleaning of the plugs make the sound clearer?

Comment: This may help when the plugs are in a really nasty condition. Don't think it will make any difference in your case.

Answer (score 3):

I've always found a contact cleaner, such as plastic-safe [DeoxIT](http://www.guitarcenter.com/CAIG-DeoxIT-D5S-6-Spray--Contact-Cleaner---Rejuvenator--5-oz--101175859-i1134929.gc), works wonders for these types of connections. I normally spritz some on the plug itself, then work the plug in and out of the port a few times, spritz again, remove excess,  plug in and go.